# Multiple coloured box plots in R with legends

Tags: r

I have a raw data which looks like this:
       A  B     C    D  E    F    G     H    I    J    K  L  M  N    O     P
    1 15.0 20  23.3 26.5 28 29.0 31.8  32.0 32.0 33.8 36.0 38 40 46 47.0  55.0
    2 10.0 13  16.0 20.0 10 19.5 14.0  15.0 31.0 15.0 24.6 29 31 46 26.7  38.2
    3 18.0 25  29.5 45.0 47 36.5 41.0  38.0 34.5 63.0 43.0 41 42 55 55.0  78.0
    4 32.5 60 108.7 88.0 83 65.9 84.9 125.1 62.6 83.0 71.6 53 55 72 88.3 123.8
    5 22.0 36  65.0 63.0 60 43.8 53.0  74.0 44.3 71.0 50.3 44 46 62 63.5  96.0
    6 10.0 NA    NA   NA 30   NA   NA    NA   NA 20.0   NA NA NA NA   NA    NA
    7 15.0 NA    NA   NA 25   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA   NA NA NA NA   NA    NA
    8  5.0 NA    NA   NA 40   NA   NA    NA   NA 30.0   NA NA NA NA   NA    NA

These are actually the 2.5, 25, 50, 75 and 97.5 percentile values. I want to create box plots from these with different colours each and then mark the median point with a dot in the boxplot. I tried writing the following commands but got stuck with an error I could not comprehend.

```
Boxplot <- read.csv(file="Boxplots.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")
Boxplot
attach(Boxplot)
boxplot(Boxplot, las = 2, col = c("sienna","royalblue2","chartreuse3","chartreuse4","chocolate","chocolate1","chocolate2","chocolate3","chocolate4","coral","coral1","coral2","coral3","coral4","cornflowerblue"), 
        at = c(1,2,3,4,5, 6,7,8,9, 10,11,12,13,14,15), par(mar = c(0, 5, 4, 2) + 0.1), 
        names = c("","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""))
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would (always) steer clear of `attach`.  Especially here because you've already assigned `Boxplot` to your data, so it's already "attached".  The error you're getting is likely due to the length of your `col` argument being longer than the number of columns.

```
> dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "A       B       C       D       E       F       G
  15.0    20.0    23.3    26.5    28.0    29.0    31.8
  10.0    13.0    16.0    20.0    10.0    19.5    14.0
  18.0    25.0    29.5    45.0    47.0    36.5    41.0
  32.5    60.0    108.7   88.0    83.0    65.9    84.9
  22.0    36.0    65.0    63.0    60.0    43.8    53.0")

> boxplot(dat, col = rainbow(7), medlwd = 0)
> points(sapply(dat, median), pch = 19)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much sir. Each of these column values are a combination of various sub-categories. Would it be possible to mark the median points of, say, 2 or 3 of those categories on these box plots?

Comment: Yes, probably.  Are they in a different data frame?

Comment: Yes Sir, there is a subset for each category that's gone into making each column so that is available separately (I mean the percentiles have been taken out for that individual subset as well).

Comment: Sure.  As an example, `points(sapply(dat, sd), pch = 19, col = rainbow(7))` will add colored standard deviation points to each column.  Please add what you want to the original post and we'll get there.

Comment: Sir, I have modified the data. As you would see, there are extra values for Columns A, E and J (rows named X,Y,Z). These are median values of 3 sub-categories. Is it possible to mark these on their respective boxplots with different signs say cross, triangle, circle etc.

Comment: Also, is it possible to assign specific colours to specific box plots? Like A will be yellow, F red and the rest Green. I am being able to change colours adding steps to the command you provided me but not being able to assign specific colours. Thanks for all the help sir. I am a beginner in R and your much valued help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you'd just use `col = c("yellow", "red", ...)`.  The colors go in the same order as the boxplots.  So in `col = c("yellow", "red", ...)`, yellow is applied to A, red to B, and so on.

Comment: Sir, I figured out the colour issue. Its working and the box plots look great. Its just the extra median values that I am now struggling with. Could you access the modified table values I updated?

Comment: yeah, I know I messed it up. I don't even know how to put it the way you edited. how do I put the data as a table?

Comment: Paste the result of `dput(data)`

Comment: Are the values `30 20  7 15 25  8  5 40 30`?

Comment: No sir, there are 3 more rows after the normal rows named X,Y,Z. These can be considered to be 3 subsets. I have values 10, 15, 5 for X,Y,Z for column A. 30,25,50 FOR COLUMN F and 20, <blank>, 30 for column J. These are the median values for the 3 sub sets that I am trying to plot in their respective boxplots in 3 different shapes

Comment: Could you comprehend it sir?